# Netsuite - How to replace a single quote via mass update

Tags: netsuite

I am trying to replace all of the single quotes in a field with the number 20. Basically, the field contains a year but when they were brought into Netsuite it was done so as '20 {for 2020} but we need  to change it to be 2020 instead.

I tried the following formula in the mass update for that field but am getting a syntax error and am not sure why because I thought I was escaping the character correctly:

```
REPLACE(''''20', ''' , '20')
```

The idea is to replace all of the single quotes where the string is '20 to 2020.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find it easier to explicitly specify the single quote with the `CHR()` function, to avoid escaping confusion:

```
REPLACE(CHR(39) || '20', CHR(39) , '20')
```

Comment: Note the first parameter would normally be the field in question and it would be be better to expand the match so it doesn't replace other single quotes. So: `REPLACE({somefield}, CHR(39) || '20', '2020')`